# Remove label from custom Highcharts drawing

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've created a custom [Highcharts drawing](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/renderer), and I currently have it where it displays a label if the user mouses over an element. However, I want to remove the label on mouseout.

This is what I have so far:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
  chart: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    events: {
      load: function () {
        var ren = this.renderer;

        ren.rect(50, 50, 60, 50, 0)
          .attr({
            'stroke-width': 2
          })
          .on('mouseover', function() {
            ren.label('Foo')
            .attr({
              fill: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
              padding: 10,
              r: 5,
              zIndex: 8
            })
            .css({
              color: '#fff'
            })
            .add();
          })
          .on('mouseout', function() {
            // need to remove the Foo label here
          })
          .add();
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: it would help if you can set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) then edit your question to bump it to the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an element this way:

```
var myRect = renderer.rect(x, y, w, h, r);
```

then you have access to your rect using `myRect` variable.

Now you can call all methods from [Element](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Element) object:

```
myRect.add();
myRect.on( ... );
myRect.destroy(); // remove element from DOM
```